# Make tkinter Label disappear after time - "NoneType" Object has no attribute "destroy"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label, attributeerror

please excuse if the following problem is a super stupid mistake on my side. Im very new to coding and despite some similar problems here which have been solved already, I still can't figure out, why Im running into the following Error message within my specific code:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/**init**.py",
> line 1883, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "/Users/Tomasz/Desktop/Code/04_OtherCodes/patch_app/app.py", line 64,
> in clear_inputs
> master.after(2000, vis.destroy()) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Basically I'm trying to write a function, which clears all inputs in a tkinter form and displays a success message below. In order to being able to reuse the grid for more messages later on, I have to get rid of the message after a certain (short) time - let's say 2 seconds. Here is what I got so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

master = Tk()
master.title("Patch Organizer")
master.geometry("620x500")
message = ""

### Defining several variables and input Fields in between
### And listing them all in a list input_fields = [entry1, entry2, entry3, etc]


def clear_inputs():
    global input_fields, message
    for field in input_fields:
        field.delete(0, END)

    message = "All clear - let's start all over!"
    vis= Label(master, fg = "green", text= message).grid(row=4,column=1)
    master.after(2000, vis.destroy())

mainloop()
```

Why cant I call the method destroy on tkinters Label Object?
And maybe there is also a better way? Like calling a function which sets the message again back to an empty string?

Thanks so much for your help!

Cheers
jaq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to do the grid method seperate and then you need to put lambda before the command, otherwise it happens immediately.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

master = Tk()
master.title("Patch Organizer")
master.geometry("620x500")
message = ""

### Defining several variables and input Fields in between
### And listing them all in a list input_fields = [entry1, entry2, entry3, etc]

def clear_inputs(event):
    message =("All clear - let's start all over!")
    vis= Label(master, fg = "green", text= message)
    vis.grid(row=4,column=1)
    master.after(2000, lambda:vis.destroy())

e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid()
e1.bind("<Return>", clear_inputs)



mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The separation helped indeed!

Comment: For a detailed explanation check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/63079747/13629335

Answer (score 0):

*Do it like this*

```py
vis= Label(master, fg = "green", text= message)
vis.grid(row=4,column=1)
```