# Tkinter grid_forget is clearing the frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
    from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
root=Tk()
root.title("Image Viewer")

def buttonforward(image_number):
    global myLabel
    myLabel.grid_forget()

    myLabel = Label(image=imagelist[image_number-1])
    myLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    return
my_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('mountain1.jpg'))
my_img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('mountain2.jpg'))
my_img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('mountain3.jpg'))
my_img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('mountain4.jpg'))
my_img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('mountain5.jpg'))

myLabel = Label(image=my_img1, ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
imagelist = [my_img1, my_img2, my_img3, my_img4, my_img5]
button_back = Button(root, text='<<').grid(row=1,column=0)
button_exit = Button(root, text='Exit', padx=60, command=root.quit).grid(padx=60, row=1,column=1)
button_forward = Button(root, text='>>',command = lambda: buttonforward(2) ).grid(row=1,column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

myLabel.grid_forget() is not working and I am encountering the following error after I press the forward '>>' button:
myLabel.grid_forget()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid_forget'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seperate the grid method and it will work. [Every function in Python needs to return something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function/62742314#62742314) and if nothing is returned 'None' will set by default. So your variable will become `myLabel = None`.

Now that you know why that is bad behavior your should also do it for every other widget in your code.

.

### Explaination

To show you what went wrong in your code look at this bit of code here:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
x1 = tk.Label(text='x1')
x1.pack()
print(x1)
root.mainloop()
```

the Output should be:

```
.!label
```

**This tells me that x1 is assigned to the label.**

Now take a look at this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

x1 = tk.Label(text='x1')
returned_by_layoutmanager = x1.pack()
print(x1)
print(returned_by_layoutmanager)
root.mainloop()
```

Your Output will be:

```
.!label
None
```

**If you may noticed, `None` was *returned* by the layoutmanger.**
This is how python works, as soon as somthing is returned by a method/function the interpreter *returns* to the point he started reading the function/method. It's like the function tells *I'm done* keep going.

So if you do this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
x2 = tk.Label(text='x2').pack()
print(x2)
root.mainloop()
```

Your Output will be:

```
None
```

**To understand why `None` is assigned to x2 and not to `.!label` by this line here:**

```
x2 = tk.Label(text='x2').pack()
```

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

x1 = tk.Label(text='x1')
x1 = x1.pack()
print(x1)

root.mainloop()
```

Your Output will be:

```
None
```

**Its just the same as you do it in your oneliner.** First **you assign x1** to the instance of `Label` class and then you assign x1 **to** **`None`**.