# Why I cannot use tkinter geometry manager grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'am trying to build a simple tkinter GUI but I got this error:

*_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack*

Here is my code:

```
file_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
file_menu.add_command(label='New')
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label='Exit', command=_quit)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_menu)

help_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
help_menu.add_command(label='About')
menu_bar.add_cascade(label='Help', menu=help_menu)

tab_controller = ttk.Notebook(win)

tab_1 = ttk.Frame(tab_controller)
tab_controller.add(tab_1, text='NOAA')

tab_2 = ttk.Frame(tab_controller)
tab_controller.add(tab_2, text='Station IDs')

tab_3 = ttk.Frame(tab_controller)
tab_controller.add(tab_3, text='Images')

tab_4 = ttk.Frame(tab_controller)
tab_controller.add(tab_4, text='Open Weather Map')

tab_controller.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

weather_conditions_label_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(tab_1, text='Current Weather Conditions').grid(column=0, row=1,                                                                                            padx=WEATHER_CONDITIONS_LABEL_FRAME_PAD_X,                                                                                            pady=WEATHER_CONDITIONS_LABEL_FRAME_PAD_Y)

ttk.Label(weather_conditions_label_frame, text='Last Update').grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='E')
last_update_entry_var = tk.StringVar()
last_update_entry = ttk.Entry(weather_conditions_label_frame, width=ENTRY_WIDTH, textvariable=last_update_entry_var, state='readonly')
last_update_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='W')
```

Any idea?

Comment: That's exactly what it is: you need to make a choice for the geometry manager and then stick to one geometry manager for all widgets in the parent widget.

Comment: You may want to take look on this answer here too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63079633/tkinter-grid-forget-is-clearing-the-frame/63079747#63079747

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`weather_conditions_label_frame` is `None` because you do `windows_conditions_label_frame = LabelFrame(...).grid(...)`. Later, you do `ttk.Entry(weather_conditions_label_frame, ...)` which places the entry in the root window since the master is `None`. `tab_controller` was already added to the root window with `pack`, so when you try to call `grid` you get the error.

The solution is to separate widget creation from widget layout:

```
weather_conditions_label_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(...)
weather_conditions_label_frame.grid(...)
```