# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'(tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to submit the form submission using tkinter.But i got an error stating 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'.I don't know why it happend.

```
def onsubmit():
    
    email=email_entry.get()

    myconn = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root",password = 
    "",database="project")
    cur = myconn.cursor()
    sql1="INSERT INTO 
    register(name,email,gender,qualification,courses,username,password)values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    values=[(name,email,gender,qualification,check_list,username,password)]
    cur.executemany(sql1,values)
    myconn.commit()
    myconn .close()

global email_in

lemail=Label(root,text="Email",width=20,font=("bold",10)).place(x=80,y=180)
email_entry=Entry(root).place(x=240,y=180)

sub=Button(root,text="Submit",bg='brown',fg='white',width=20,command=onsubmit).place(x=160,y=480)

root.mainloop()
```

error shown in below

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PYTHON\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Softech/Desktop/pr.py", line 25, in onsubmit
    email=email_entry.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Ive added a detailed answer on how to fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is very simple, instead of saying `place()` in the same line, instead say:

```
email_entry=Entry(root)
email_entry.place(x=240,y=180)
```

Now everything will be fixed.

This is because `email_entry=Entry(root).place(x=240,y=180)` return `None`, ie, when you use `email_entry.get()` you are saying `email_entry=Entry(root).place(x=240,y=180).get()` which does not exist in the first place and since `email_entry=Entry(root).place(x=240,y=180)` is `None` they give error, you received.

Extra fixes:

- You can remove `global` in the main block since its of no use in there.
- I think, your `values` should be a tuple rather than a tuple inside of list so change that to

```
values=(name,email,gender,qualification,check_list,username,password)
```

Cheers

Comment: You have the right answer and it should be accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63079633/tkinter-grid-forget-is-clearing-the-frame/63079747#63079747

Comment: @Atlas435 sad :(, but this is life xp

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable `email_txt = StringVar()`

modify this `email_entry=Entry(root).place(x=240,y=180)` to

`email_entry=Entry(root, textvariable=email_txt).place(x=240,y=180)`

In the function, modify

`email=email_entry.get()` to `email=email_txt.get()`

Comment: Yes, this is a way around, but if the user tries to delete whats inside of the entry box later on, itll give the same error, so its recommended to not use geometric managers in the same line as the declaration

Comment: Yeah, that's a valid point didn't think of that earlier