# Why can I not use the get attribute in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("850x900")
def pri():
    user = e.get()
    print(user)
e = Entry(root).pack()
b = Button(root, text = "Submit", command=pri).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63079633/tkinter-grid-forget-is-clearing-the-frame/63079747#63079747

Comment: You define the function ``pri`` before you define your entry ``e``. You have to define the function last. "NoneType" means that the object ``e`` hasn't been defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to assign, to a variable, the result of a function that does not return anything (`pack`). You could first assign the `Entry` widget to the variable `e` and then pack. The following code works:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("850x900")
def pri():
    user = e.get()
    print(user)
e=Entry(root)
e.pack()
Button(root, text = "Submit", command=pri).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Sioul - If this answer solved your problem then you need to accept it (ie click the big grey check-mark to the left of the answer).