# Difference between writing Layout management in one line and two line in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

Can someone explain me the difference between writing layout management in this format i.e, in two lines

```
e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=x)
e1.grid(row=1, column=2)
```

and writing layout management in this format i.e., in one line

```
e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=x).grid(row=1, column=2)
```

Why can't I use `get()` when I write layout management in single line.

Comment: It is because `Entry(...).grid(...)` returns the result of `grid(...)` which is `None`.  For latest Python 3.8.x, you can use `(e1 := Entry(...)).grid(...)`.

Comment: See my answer on this question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63079747/13629335

Answer (score 1):

In python, when you do `x=y().z()`, `x` is set to the result of `.z()`.

`pack`, `grid`, and `place` all are designed to return `None`. Thus, `e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=x).grid(row=1, column=2)` return `None` So `e1` is `None`. The value `None` doesn’t have any methods which is why you get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

Further, in my experience, it is always better to separate widget creation from widget layout. Trying to put it all on one line makes the code harder to understand and harder to maintain. By separating the code and grouping layout commands together it makes it much easier to visualize the layout just by looking at the code.